# Adding value to strings in an array

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add int/uint values to each of the string array strings("Item1") instead of the default ones 0-5 in this case

```
                string[] items = new string[5]
            {
                "Item1",
                "Item2",
                "Item3",
                "Item4",
                "Item5"
            };
```

Im trying to add a value to each of the ("Item1","Item2"...) inside the array is that possible?

Comment: could you elaborate on what you want?  for example, what should the sample array look like after the desired operation is performed.

Comment: I want the array to look the same, i just want for the output of the strings to be a custom value (Ingame items real ID value) instead of the arrays default return value.

Somehow i want to see if its possible to attach "Item1" a custom int = 1000 value for an example

Comment: Then [edit] your post and put that information there, so that it's part of the question. Burying it in comments isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but why not use a Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, int> items = new Dictionary<string, int>();

items.Add("Item1", 1001);
items.Add("Item2", 1002);
items.Add("Item3", 1003);
items.Add("Item4", 1004);
items.Add("Item5", 1005);
```

You can then get the ID corresponding to an Item as follows

```
items["Item1"]; //Should give you 1001
```

**Example**

```
foreach(var item in items.Keys){
    Console.WriteLine (item + ":" + items[item]);
}
```

**Output**

```
Item1:1001
Item2:1002
Item3:1003
Item4:1004
Item5:1005
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use classes :

```
class Item
{
     int ItemId {get; set;}
     string ItemName {get;set;}
}
```

and then use it like this :

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
item.Add(new Item{ ItemId = 1,ItemName = "First"});
item.Add(new Item{ ItemId = 2,ItemName = "Second"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("Item1", 1000);
```

If you want to initialize the items more easily you can declare it in one line like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(){{"Item1", 1},{"Item2", 2}};
```